# scipy.linalg DLL load failed (Python 3.4, Windows 8.1)

Tags: python, scipy, windows-8.1, python-3.4

I have 64 bit windows 8.1, python 3.4. I have numpy and scipy installed, but I am encountering DLL errors, i.e.:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
from .blas import get_blas_funcs
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have looked through solutions like "[scipy-0.16.0-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.16.0b2/)" but there is nothing on the page for 64 bit systems.

I can't find a stack for 64 bit windows (and I don't want to use winpython, Anaconda or other distributions of python. I am hoping to find something that will work with my standard python distribution). Is there a package or stack somewhere that I can install, without having to hunt down DLLs one at a time? I'm a newbie here, appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The whole point of binary distributions like `anaconda`  or `winpython` is to solve exactly that problem for you. I would highly recommend reconsidering if you really want to avoid them.
If you do, another option you have is to grab a binary wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Comment: Thanks I have Anaconda and winpython, but I am trying to get this to work on the standard version as much as possible. The script might need to be shared to other machines, which might not have Anaconda or winpython installed.